# Applying a class to every 1st and 4th item

Tags: jquery, list, addclass

I have a list of 16 items. There are 4 rows with 4 items on each row. 
How can I add a class '.first' to the first item of each row and '.fourth' to the fourth item of each row.

Resulting:

```
<ul>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="fourth"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Probably you just need nth-child() selector? See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
     // You can use a more specific li selector as per your requirement
    $("li").each(function(a, b){
        if(a%4 == 0){
            $(b).addClass("first");
        }
        if(a%4 == 3){
            $(b).addClass("fourth");
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Using nth-child:

```
$(function(){
    var ul = $("ul");//You can use more specific UL
    ul.find(":nth-child(4n-3)").addClass("first");
    ul.find(":nth-child(4n)").addClass("fourth");
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qmHNQ/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the CSS selectors :nth-child or :nth-of-type. You can use them in jQuery to add the classes, or you can use them as pseudo-classes directly and skip adding the extra attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use each(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
jQuery.each('ul li', function(indexInArray, valueOfElement){
    if ((indexInArray % 4) == 0) { $(this).addClass('first'); }
    if ((indexInArray % 4) == 3) { $(this).addClass('fourth'); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you can use the ":even" filter twice.  The first time, you would get all the ones divisible by 2, the second :even would give you all the evens of that... divisible by 4.

```
$("li:gt(0):even:even").addClass("fourth");
```

To set the 1st, 5th, etc... you could probably get all the li's except the first and apply the class "first".  Then, set the first one as well.

```
$("li:first").addClass("first");
$("li:gt(1):even:even").addClass("first");
```

Ok... this does work, but it looks like it was one off.  This should work.